# How to adjust size of the Treeview to full screen width and height?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to adjust the size of tkinter Treeview window but it's not working. Below I will attach the code which I'm working with.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.title('Excel To Treeview')
root.geometry("2800x1600")

# Create frame
my_frame = Frame(root)
#my_frame.config(width = 100)
my_frame.pack(pady=20)

# Create treeview
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(my_frame)
my_tree.config()

# File open function
def file_open():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/home/ashanglenn",
        title = "Open A File",
        filetypes=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files", "*.*"))
        )

    if filename:
        try:
            filename = r"{}".format(filename)
            df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        except ValueError:
            my_label.config(text="File Couldn't Be Opened...try again!")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            my_label.config(text="File Couldn't Be Found...try again!")
    # Clear old treeview
    clear_tree()

    # Set up new treeview
    my_tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
    my_tree["show"] = "headings"
    # Loop thru column list for headers
    for column in my_tree["column"]:
        my_tree.heading(column, text=column)

    # Put data in treeview
    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        my_tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

    # Pack the treeview finally
    my_tree.pack()


def clear_tree():
    my_tree.delete(*my_tree.get_children())

# Add a menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

# Add menu dropdown
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Spreadsheets", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=file_open)

my_label = Label(root, text='')
my_label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

so as I mentioned when I open the excel file via the menu "Spreadsheets -> Open" it will open the Treeview window for a fixed size, no matter what size of columns and rows the excel file contains it open up to a fixed size. So I want to extend the size of this Treeview to the full screen size of the window. For better understanding I have attached a picture of this program with this google drive link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12pzYW1G6-GNN0eO03zMK2U1sglaY6SBz/view?usp=sharing

I'm pretty new to Python and still learning basics. I would really appreciate your valuable help. Hope the question is clear! Thank You.

Comment: Change `my_frame.pack(pady=20)` to `my_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1, pady=20)` and `my_tree.pack()` to `my_tree.pack(fill="both", expand=1)`.

Comment: It worked :D You are a lifesaver @acw1668 :) Really appreciate your help.